# Add user input to list on button click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an HTML form which takes the text from multiple textboxes (in this case, 3) and adds the content of each to a list in a separate div, as well as create a new object "employee", all via the click of a button. My goal is to imitate adding employees to a database, using an employee id, first name, and last name as variables. I am looking to accomplish this using pure javascript.

What I have so far is:

```
<form>
  ID Number:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="idNumber">
  <br>First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="firstName">
  <br>Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
</form>
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction(list)">Submit</button>

<div id="container">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

In a separate JavaScript file:

```
function myFunction(list){
  var text = document.getElementById("idNumber","fName","lName").value; 
  var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
  document.getElementById("list").replaceChild(li);
}
```

When I debug my code it seems to be setting the values fine, but I receive no actual output of my list.

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName` doesn’t exist and the `document.getElementsByClassName` function that you mean doesn’t work like that at all. The arguments you’re giving that function aren’t even class names.

Comment: to check if your code is wrong make the var li = "<li> sample text </li>" if that doesnt shows up a list, you are doing it wrong

Comment: If you are getting element by `Id` wouldn't you want to make sure you have an `id` in your inputs? you have it for the first input but not for the others.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith was trying to make it work using one variable at first, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the input elements you selected had a class name. You can also do this with `document.getElementById`. Just add ids to all your form elements.

Your code should look something like this.

```
function myFunction(list){
    var text = "";
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        text += inputs[i].value;
    }
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    li.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/nb5h4o7o/3/

Your list wasn't being appended to because you weren't actually creating the elements. `replaceChild` should have been `appendChild` and you should have created a list element with `document.createElement`.

Comment: This accomplishes what I was looking for, clearly I've got some practicing to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of problems, look at the [`document.getElementById`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/getelementbyid) and [`Node.replaceChild`](http://devdocs.io/dom/node/replacechild) docs.

I've created a version for you that we get all the  `input` elements of your form (using [`querySelectorAll`](http://devdocs.io/dom/element/queryselectorall)), and then we use [`Array.prototype.map`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map) to turn them into `"<li>[value]</li>"`, and then [`Array.prototype.join`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/join) to turn that array into a single string.

Then, we get that string and set the [`#list.innerHTML`](http://devdocs.io/dom/element/innerhtml) property.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var form = document.querySelector('form'),
      list = document.getElementById('list');
  
  list.innerHTML = [].map.call(form.querySelectorAll('input'), function(el) {
    return '<li>' + el.value + '</li>';
  }).join('');
});
```

```html
<form>
  ID Number:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="idNumber">
  <br>First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="firstName">
  <br>Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
</form>
<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="container">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```